# Basketball Physics Collision Detection and Bounce Physics

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

I am making a basketball physics simulator. I am am using a parametric equation to calculate the path of the ball. I am having a hard time with collision detection with the front of the rim, backboard, pole, and the court floor (bottom of canvas). Additionally I want to make the ball bounce when hitting these objects but I am having a hard time. Can anyone offer some help with this problem?

Here is the code snippet:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, canvas.height)
ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

var speed = 5;
var gravity = 16;
var bounce = 10;

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

var stage = 1;

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var xOrgn = 0;
var yOrgn = 0;
var xClk = 175;
var yClk = 100;
var mag = 0;
var ang = 0;
var xVel = 0;
var yVel = 0;
var time = 0;

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 12, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF8C00";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.moveTo(x, y + 12);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y - 12);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.moveTo(x - 12, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + 12, y);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.moveTo(x - 8, y - 8);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x - 2, y - 4, x - 2, y + 4, x - 8, y + 8);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.moveTo(x + 8, y - 8);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + 2, y - 4, x + 2, y + 4, x + 8, y + 8);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawHoop() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(228, -160, 12, 172);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#191919";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(222, -12, 6, 80);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#666666";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(171, -6, 51, 6);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#e50000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(171, -3, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#e50000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawCursor() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.moveTo(mouseX - 12, mouseY);
  ctx.lineTo(mouseX + 12, mouseY);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#00cd00';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY - 12);
  ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY + 12);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#00cd00';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function calcVel() {
  mag = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(xClk - xOrgn, 2) + Math.pow(yClk - yOrgn, 2)) / 4);
  ang = Math.atan((yClk - yOrgn) / (xClk - xOrgn));
  xVel = mag * Math.cos(ang);
  yVel = mag * Math.sin(ang);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(-(canvas.width / 2), -(canvas.height / 2), canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft - canvas.width / 2;
    mouseY = -event.clientY + ctx.canvas.offsetTop + canvas.height / 2;
  });
  drawBall();
  drawHoop();
  if (stage === 1) {
    x = mouseX;
    y = mouseY;
    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      xOrgn = x;
      yOrgn = y;
      stage = 2;
    });
  } else if (stage === 2) {
    drawCursor();
    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      xClk = mouseX;
      yclk = mouseY;
      calcVel();
      time = 0;
      stage = 3;
    });
  } else if (stage === 3) {
    x = xVel * time + xOrgn;
    y = -gravity * Math.pow(time, 2) + yVel * time + yOrgn;
    time = time + speed * 0.01;
  }
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```css
canvas {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

Here is the code in jsfiddle: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Haakam/9d31qw01/)

Comment: Possible help: keep track of the old and new x,y values and then see if the ball moved 'through" the rim or backboard. Because you're incrementing the x,y values by more than 1, you can't check for equality: the ball could be above the hoop in one draw and below it in the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add collision detection in "Stage 3" only. Since the locations and sizes of everything are hardcoded, it's pretty *simple* to add in collision detection item by item. (but if you make this much more complicated, I would add in some variables or objects that make it easy to get the positions of things as variables, etc).

I added in a horizontal bounce when the ball hits the backboard, and a vertical bounce off the floor. Any others are similar.

(Note, what made these possible were updating x and y (and xVel, yVel) iteratively rather than from a determined equation. The results are the same, but the calculation and dynamic behaviour are easier).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, canvas.height)
ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

var speed = 5;
var gravity = 16;
var bounce = 10;

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

var stage = 1;

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var xOrgn = 0;
var yOrgn = 0;
var xClk = 175;
var yClk = 100;
var mag = 0;
var ang = 0;
var xVel = 0;
var yVel = 0;
var time = 0;

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 12, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF8C00";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.moveTo(x, y + 12);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y - 12);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.moveTo(x - 12, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + 12, y);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.moveTo(x - 8, y - 8);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x - 2, y - 4, x - 2, y + 4, x - 8, y + 8);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.moveTo(x + 8, y - 8);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + 2, y - 4, x + 2, y + 4, x + 8, y + 8);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawHoop() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(228, -160, 12, 172);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#191919";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(222, -12, 6, 80);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#666666";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(171, -6, 51, 6);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#e50000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(171, -3, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#e50000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawCursor() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.moveTo(mouseX - 12, mouseY);
  ctx.lineTo(mouseX + 12, mouseY);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#00cd00';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY - 12);
  ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY + 12);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#00cd00';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function calcVel() {
  mag = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(xClk - xOrgn, 2) + Math.pow(yClk - yOrgn, 2)) / 4);
  ang = Math.atan((yClk - yOrgn) / (xClk - xOrgn));
  xVel = mag * Math.cos(ang);
  yVel = mag * Math.sin(ang);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(-(canvas.width / 2), -(canvas.height / 2), canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft - canvas.width / 2;
    mouseY = -event.clientY + ctx.canvas.offsetTop + canvas.height / 2;
  });
  drawBall();
  drawHoop();
  if (stage === 1) {
    x = mouseX;
    y = mouseY;
    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      xOrgn = x;
      yOrgn = y;
      stage = 2;
    });
  } else if (stage === 2) {
    drawCursor();
    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      xClk = mouseX;
      yclk = mouseY;
      calcVel();
      time = 0;
      stage = 3;
    });
  } else if (stage === 3) {
    //x = xVel * time + xOrgn;
    // update x from it's own value so we can vary the xVel.
    x += xVel * speed * 0.01;

    //y = -gravity * Math.pow(time, 2) + yVel * time + yOrgn;
    // update yVel and y iteratively instead of this determined calculation
    //y = -gravity * Math.pow(time, 2) + yVel * time + yOrgn;
    yVel -= gravity * 0.1;
    y += yVel * speed * 0.01;

    // do a collision check: the backboard.
    if (x > 222 - 12 && y > -12 && y < 62) {
     xVel *= -1;
    }
    // with floor
    if(y <= -142) {
        y = -142;
        yVel *= -1;
    }
    time = time + speed * 0.01;
  }
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```css
canvas {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

You can handle any other collisions you want similarly

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will use variables for the positions of objects. This has worked great for me!

Comment: Glad it's working! What I mean by variables is, it would be great if you could type something like `if (x > backboard.x)` or better yet `if (backboard.intersects(x,y))`. You can make it all work with variables as you have (and that is a good first step!), but it would be more readable and have fewer "magic numbers" if you can do it this way.